# How to 3x or 4x a DC voltage while minimizing board space with no microcontroller?

Tags: voltage, boost, charge-pump, voltage-doubler

I have a 3.7V DC voltage source that I'd like to boost to at least 10 Volts.

I've been using Microchip's TC7660 component as a voltage doubler. But it only comes in SOIC (rather large for SMT). And since it can only double voltages, to get to 10 volts, I would have to use two of them as a voltage quadrupler (plus four diodes, also rather large).

There are actually a lot of components for increasing a DC voltage, especially in the context of microcontrollers and "erasing" RAM memory. But I can't seem to find a way to efficiently boost this voltage. I suppose I'm looking for efficiency both in terms of space on the board and in terms of price. Right now Microchip's solution adds about $2.50 per board including the diodes and capacitors which is really high. When you add in the design considerations due to the large board space it is really a lot more than that for something I think could be done better.

There's also a lot of confusing or seemingly overlapping concepts when I try to research this: Boost converters, charge pumps, etc. Most of the results when I research this are about AC to DC conversion which is really frustrating to research this. I've looked into arranging batteries in series or even non-Lipo batteries, but all other solutions seem to be too big.

Ideally I would have a single SOIC or two smaller components for getting this 3.7 V to 10V. Something else using rudimentary components (e.g. transistors) would also work.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: What exactly is the 10v supposed to power?  What are the acceptable limits for voltage and ripple?  How much current?  How tolerant is it of noise?

Comment: It powers an op-amp. Only about 1mA of current. Noise doesn't matter thankfully (can be a very noisy signal).

Comment: TC7660 is by Microchip, not TI, right?

Comment: Try a super small boost converter? TI web bench has many options.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want the output to change when the input does... that clearly distinguishes your need from "doubler" or "quadrupler".

Comment: This TI web bench is like porn. I can't believe it calculates every single parameter that I mentioned for you. My post probably reads like an advertisement for this web bench (but it isn't)

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess? I really don't know, I just need to 2x/4x a static power supply (so yea, no change when the input changes)

Comment: Do you need to multiply the input voltage (ie. you want 4*3.7) or do you need 10V?  10V is the job of a boost converter.  Multiplying is a separate thing that can be done as well, but may not actually fit your needs.

Comment: ^ Either one is fine, whatever is easier. Between 10 and 15 Volts is the goal of the output. It is for a biological system so there is a lot of noise in the end-system/end-sensor already

Comment: If there's already a bunch of noise, then you don't want to be adding noise to it.  That said, a boost converter really is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks. In this biocontext it's really okay, trust me.  Yes, I love the web bench

Comment: There are many small SOT23 boost converters, that's what I'd be after

Comment: Use a Joule Thief configuration with a zener and capacitor on the output.

Comment: @Kripacharya  would you like to formulate that as an answer? It doesn't seem to be an easy thing to learn to calculate but probably minimizing the size of the inductor and cost of the transformer would be the only factors. However I can use the current pulses as pulses (no need for a diode / capactitor at the end)

Comment: Just Google Joule Thief. There's heaps of information out there. The design is fairly non-critical. The transformer can be wound on a really small (T25-2)  toroid.

Comment: Thanks I am looking it up now... I want to make this on an SMT board though using manufactured components... So aren't things like the distance between the two toroids and using an SMT inductor instead of hand-winding a factor? I could probably make this by hand, but I'd rather be able to do some math to calculate it for an SMT board... I just am not finding many equations on this... I do want to use / learn more about this joule thief concept because it seems like something that would be really useful / life-saving in an apocalyptic scenario

Comment: This calculator is pretty helpful: https://www.systemvision.com/design/joule-thief-transformer-physical-design